# android display loading image while rotate

Tags: android, image, rotation, loading

I have an Android apk which mainly is a webview to access html5 web. Every time when I rotate screen, it displays a blank screen while reloading/rerendering web page. Since web pages need to get data through server, it may take a few seconds.

I am just wondering, is there an easy way to display a loading image or a logo image, instead of blank screen, while rotating?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) callbacks as described in [WebView spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) together with showing [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) of type

`style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"` for example.

Your activity should include something like this:

```
private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

        spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    }

    private WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
        {
            if(progress == 100)
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
        };
```

and a progress bar should be defined in your xml layout:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```